Error running solana-test-validator in wsl
I am using WSL.
I have followed the steps laid out in the solana documentation for setting up the development environment (https://solana.com/docs/intro/installation#run-local-validator).
Solana CLI is installed correctly: 
I am able to write to the directory I am currently in (I have created my-test-file.txt for demonstration purposes): 
But when I want to run solana-test-validator I am getting an error: 
If I navigate to the test-ledger folder which was created during the command execution, and I cat validator.log, this is the output I am getting:
    [2024-12-23T13:19:36.508297901Z INFO  solana_test_validator] agave-validator 2.0.21 (src:99ac0105; feat:607245837, client:Agave)
[2024-12-23T13:19:36.508314426Z INFO  solana_test_validator] Starting validator with: ArgsOs {
        inner: [
            "solana-test-validator",
        ],
    }
[2024-12-23T13:19:36.508330635Z WARN  solana_perf] CUDA is disabled
[2024-12-23T13:19:36.508338172Z INFO  solana_perf] AVX detected
[2024-12-23T13:19:36.508339651Z INFO  solana_perf] AVX2 detected
[2024-12-23T13:19:36.509865704Z INFO  solana_faucet::faucet] Faucet started. Listening on: 0.0.0.0:9900
[2024-12-23T13:19:36.509881881Z INFO  solana_faucet::faucet] Faucet account address: 454GkhoBrropULEoU9KXV5Z4hB9WdL5F4dgYJZ5tHpef
[2024-12-23T13:19:36.510881746Z INFO  agave_validator::admin_rpc_service] started admin rpc service!
[2024-12-23T13:19:36.513838560Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] Maximum open file descriptors: 1000000
[2024-12-23T13:19:36.513855585Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] Opening blockstore at "test-ledger/rocksdb"
[2024-12-23T13:19:36.516932242Z WARN  solana_ledger::blockstore_db] Unable to detect Rocks columns: Error { message: "IO error: No such file or directory: While opening a file for sequentially reading: test-ledger/rocksdb/CURRENT: No such file or directory" }
[2024-12-23T13:19:36.673046697Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] Opening blockstore done; blockstore open took 159ms
[2024-12-23T13:19:36.677649828Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] metrics disabled: environment variable not found
[2024-12-23T13:19:36.678094829Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: shred_insert_is_full slot=0i total_time_ms=0i last_index=31i num_repaired=0i num_recovered=0i
[2024-12-23T13:19:36.838214030Z ERROR solana_ledger::blockstore] tar stdout:
[2024-12-23T13:19:36.838233376Z ERROR solana_ledger::blockstore] tar stderr: /bin/sh: 1: bzip2: Permission denied
    tar: test-ledger/genesis.tar.bz2: Wrote only 4096 of 10240 bytes
    tar: Child returned status 127
    tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

How can I resolve this error?

It looks like there's still some permission issue, based on the log file:
[2024-12-23T13:19:36.838233376Z ERROR solana_ledger::blockstore] tar stderr: /bin/sh: 1: bzip2: Permission denied

Perhaps something was run under root or some other user previously. If you're ok with losing any local state in your validator, you can try to remove the whole test-ledger/ directory and re-running solana-test-validator in the hope that the user has all the permissions needed.

Thanks, but I have already tried removing the whole test-ledger folder, and running the solana-test-validator again, but I got the same error.
Do you think reinstalling the whole solana CLI could fix the problem?

Hm, I don't think reinstalling the tool suite will help unfortunately. On the other hand, v2.1 avoids shelling out for tar with https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/pull/3079, so v2.1 might resolve your issue
